# WebPack Tree Shaking for 2nd level dependencies

Tags: webpack, bundle, tree-shaking

I am building a dashboard application and a chart library (as an npm package that outputs ESM). In the dashboard application, I have installed and used the chart package, specifically some of its chart components. When building the dashboard application, the tree-shaking process is working correctly for both the dashboard application code and the library code. However, I have noticed that unused dependencies from the chart package are also bundled.

[image]

In this example, the GeoMap, LineChart, and Utils code are not included in the bundle, which is expected. However, the mapbox-gl library is included in my dashboard application bundle. I have already set "sideEffects: true" in the chart library's package.json file and "usedExports: true" in the webpack configuration for the dashboard application.

Am I missing any key configuration or guidance to ensure that only the necessary dependencies are bundled in my dashboard application?